# Alternative way of sending e-mail from app on iOS 10 when Mail app is deleted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Now that Apple's "Mail" app can be deleted in iOS 10 and using `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` is always return **NO**  when Mail app is  deleted.

Is there any alternative way for sending Mail from inside the app?

Comment: have you login any mail account ?

Comment: @Ram Yes, but with GMAIL app, MAIL app is deleted on my device

Comment: there is two reason to return always NO 
you have no account login
or the login accounts is not active

Comment: @Ram It is NO because there is no MAIL app and obviously when you don't have the app you can't login with your account ... I just need to know what are the alternative ways to send email from and inside the app ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Crashalot No, not really.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **MailCore** Framework. This is an alternative to *MFMailComposeViewController*. Using this framework you can send an email programmatically. You have to construct each and every field i.e, To,CC,BCC,Subject,body etc. by yourself using this. One important thing to remember it has no UI.

```
    CTCoreMessage *msg = [[CTCoreMessage alloc] init];
[CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:msg server:[server stringValue] username:[username stringValue]
                         password:[password stringValue] port:[port intValue] useTLS:tls useAuth:auth];
 [msg release];
```